# Bot framework web chat channel steals page focus

Tags: botframework

I embedded the URL code for my bot in my page but whenever i open this URL it automatically jumps to the BOT (which is located at the bottom of the page).

how can i prevent that?

Comment: This is a known issue with the current WebChat: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/568 and https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/587 Until there is an API for setting focus, you will need to fork the repo and modify the source to no longer have a greedy focus.

Comment: thank you :) i'm afraid i don't know how to edit the source... can you please provide more guidance?

Comment: There are some instructions on how to build and customize WebChat here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#building-web-chat

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of webchat does not have this issue (stealing focus) and allows for much greater customisation - see instructions of how to integrate: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/SAMPLES.md

Comment: Hi Jose. Can you confirm this on your end? I just cloned the webchat, added the following line to /samples/full-bundle/index.html:  **<div height="700px" style="height:700px; border-style:solid; background-color: red">something</div> above <div id="webchat"></div>** and it does indeed steal focus.

Comment: @DanaV - yes it works for me. I used the hosted script - https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js